# mutate() error - 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling, case

I'm trying to seasonally adjust a time-series using dummy variables. I have a time series `f1value` which is recorded monthly for 6 years, and I used this code to extract the average differences by month:

```
df_dummy <- dummy_cols(df, 
                       select_columns = "month")

fit <- lm(data = df_dummy, 
          formula = f1value ~ month_1 + month_2 + month_3 + month_4 + month_5 + month_6 + 
                    month_7 + month_8 + month_9 + month_10 + month_11 + month_12)
```

I then use the results of this model to determine by:

```
df_dummy %>%
  mutate(f1val_season_adj = # create new col
           case_when(
             month_1 == 1 ~ f1value - 2925, # if Jan, adj f1val by the estimate given in model
             month_2 == 1 ~ f1value - 3842,
             month_3 == 1 ~ f1value + 1235,
             month_4 == 1 ~ f1value + 6440,
             month_5 == 1 ~ f1value + 5938,
             month_6 == 1 ~ f1value + 6752,
             month_7 == 1 ~ f1value + 9491,
             month_8 == 1 ~ f1value + 7679,
             month_9 == 1 ~ f1value + 1596,
             month_10 == 1 ~ f1value + 3669,
             month_11 == 1 ~ f1value + 1735,
             month_12 == 1 ~ f1value # Dec. gets the Original value, as est. are based off month 12 base
           )
  )
```

When I run this code, I get the error `'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]`. However, I do not see what vector or 'names' attribute is being invoked here.

Comment: I also dont know what name attr is being used, but I would finish with a catch all else condición `TRUE ~ as.numeric(NA)`

Comment: @DavidJorquera This didn't change anything in the error message unfortunately

Comment: is `f1value` a column inside `df_dummy`? you should give us a reprex. Put your data or sample data inside a `dput` function to paste it into your question. Then we can reproduce the error and try a fix.